# Chinese letter binary search bug in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data with Chinese letters like below:

```
tt <- data.table(区域 = rep(c('城东', '城西', '乐清'),3), value = rnorm(9))
```

When I use '%in%' for binary search :

```
    tt[区域 %in% c('城西', '乐清')]

   区域       value
1: 城西 -1.25803227
2: 城西  0.06433707
3: 城西  1.36270354
```

It does not contain '乐清' data. But it works fine when

```
tt[区域 %in% c('城东', '城西', '乐清')]

   区域       value
1: 城东 -0.37844379
2: 城西 -1.25803227
3: 乐清  0.31931352
4: 城东 -0.81793033
5: 城西  0.06433707
6: 乐清 -0.08646208
7: 城东 -0.39817676
8: 城西  1.36270354
9: 乐清  0.74319584
```

My R version is 3.4.1, data.table version is 1.10.4. I've already switched R from 3.2.1 to 3.4.1 it doesn't work. Is that a bug or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Did you try `%chin%`, `data.table`'s dedicated `%in%` operator for characters? Not sure if it would have any effect, but can't hurt to try

Comment: @Jarko Dubbeldam yeah, it works, but why?

Comment: I have no idea. I never worked with chinese characters ever. Sorry :(